# End Coroutine if one of two conditions becomes true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, conditional-statements, coroutine

I'm not fully understanding coroutines.

If I have a coroutine that does something each frame, how do I end this looping behaviour if either of two conditions become true?

And when I say end, I also mean destroy, not put into a holding state or other paused or non completed state, so I can then restart the coroutine if a different condition becomes true.

Comment: You can use StopCoroutine? Some code might help explain your question. A coroutine is more like a function than a loop - unless you are explicitly calling the coroutine every frame. Once it runs through and returns it won't run again until started

Comment: If it contains several loops StopCoroutine is probably best. Otherwise you can just do: if(condition1||condition2) yield break;

Comment: Please provide some code. The previous comments are probably the solution, but it is hard to write a proper answer without some context.

Comment: While it often seems convenient, I would recommend avoiding coroutines where possible. A simple monobehavior can usually do the job and you have much more control.

Comment: Given I have yet to use a coroutine, a couple of months of playing with Unity, and I expressly state that I don't yet understand how to use them, you can be assured I don't see them as convenient. However, I do understand the functionality they're offering, for which certain situations do make them an easy way to think about how to solve certain issues of when to do things, for how long, in situations where it would not be simple to do in other, more traditional ways of using booleans and conditionals, or delegates to queue and do, or not. Can you explain more, this simple way, and its power?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the conditions exist outside of the coroutine, you use `StopCoroutine`:

```
var coroutine = StartCoroutine(MyRoutine());
...
if (conditionA || conditionB) {
    StopCoroutine(coroutine);
}
```

If the conditions exist inside of the coroutine, you just `yield break`:

```
IEnumerator MyRoutine() {
    while (true) {
        if (conditionA || conditionB) {
            yield break; // stop stepping this
        }
        yield return null; // continue stepping next frame
    }
}
```